# Writing to a specific csv column

Tags: java, sql-server, csv, opencsv

I have made a little javaFX app that reads from the database and writes to a file using openCSV.Everything is fine now.In the file i have a column and its values contain the path of an image(Example : /home/user/folder1/image.jpg).What i have to do is replace all the values of this column ,with another value that contains only the last folder name and the image name(Example : folder1/image.jpg).I read about this and i realised that i had to write a lot of code.What i am asking is if there is another way of doing this? For example can i replace all of this values directly from the query or can i use another library that lets me write to a specific column? 
Thanks :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `JavaFX`, so why the tag?

Comment: If all of your paths start the same, the database you are using probably has some type of function that allows you to replace the leading string with emptyString. You could also make your app replace the leading string with emptyString. One line of code could probably solve this problem. `yourString = yourString.replace("/your/common/path", "");`

Comment: `Path.relativize` or `URI.relativize` could be used... @Sedrick I'd rather do `yourString = yourString.substring("/your/common/path".length())` since you cannot be sure there are not multiple occurances of the subpath in the same path.

Comment: But opencsv doesnt allow me to write in one column only

Comment: I have constructed a method that takes a String and gives you the path so i was hoping i could do something like Replace(columnName,replaceMethod(columnName))